# Modify formula to work with conditional values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am currently using the below formula to calculate enablement costs for meters

```
=SUM(SUMIF($D74,{"New Business"}),$U74*5500)
```

This worked fine as the fee of $5500 was standard, however I now need to incorporate a new cost for a specific meter. The NZ meter is $13000.  In column F the classification is NZ Instant Reserve.

How do I maintain the above formula for the rest of my spreadsheet, but add the additional IF check for the specific meter (which only account for about 10% of my whole list).

Comment: I agree with pnuts - this part of the formula quoted `SUMIF($D74,{"New Business"})` always returns zero (no matter what value you have in D74) so your whole formula as written here can be shortened to `=U74*5500` - do you expect the result of the formula to change based on what's in D74? It won't. Either you have quoted the wrong formula here or possibly the formula will give you results you don't expect - please explain in words what the formula should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's just two values you can modify the formula along these lines:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($D74,{"New Business"}),$U74*(IF(F1="NZ Instant Reserve", 13000, 5500)))
```

You can modify the F values as needed. If there are more values you will need to switch to using a table and the LOOKUP function.

Comment: Well @pnuts if want to down vote me for apparently answering the OP's question (see his comment) then that's your right. While not the most elegant it seems to satisfy the requirement. I do think that eventually he will need a lookup table.

Comment: @pnuts np and thanks for the upvote. There are definite times when a detailed and more elegant answer are called for. Other times it seems the OP is just looking for a quick fix to their solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to store the value of "The NZ meter" at some place in another sheet and then pick up the value from there instead of hard-coding it in the formula.

Comment: I think he's looking for a formula that conditionally chooses between the 2 "NZ" values based on some other requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but yes i do get other values for new business. The New Business SUMIF check, references new customers who need a meter installed